# Significant variables for Logistic regression in R

Tags: r, model

I am still new to R and still struggling. I am trying to do a logistic regression using a categorical and continuous variable and I am supposed to select the right variable for my model. There are 27 variables and a 8,000 observations.

I have gone through a couple of articles online including stepwise regression by AIC and all I do is confuse myself the more. I was also told to select my variables from the correlation matrix but when I do the correlation I don't seem to find the correlation especially with the categorical variable. I also try to fit all the model and I get some variables with p-value less than 0.5. This is the code:

```
d4 <- d3[,c('SW','MOI','YOI','DOI_CMC','RMOB','RYOB','RDOB_CMC',
            'RCA','Region','TPR','DPR','NV','HEL','Has_Radio','Has_TV',
            'Religion','WI','MOFB','YOB','DOB_CMC','DOFB_CMC','AOR','MTFBI',
            'DSOUOM_CMC','RW','RH','RBMI')]
cor(d4)
d5 <- cor(d4)
round(cor(d4),2)
```

When I select the significant variables and try to apply logistic regression all the p value will be between 0.9 to 1. See code:

```
d3 <- lm(TPR ~ SW + MOI + RMOB + RYOB + RCA + Region + TPR + DPR +
               NV + HEL + Has_Radio + Has_TV + Religion + WI + MOFB +
               YOB + DOB_CMC + DOFB_CMC + AOR + MTFBI + DSOUOM_CMC + 
               RW + RH + RBMI,
         data = d3, family = "binomial") 
summary(d3)
```

I need help with this please!!
Here is the sample of d3
[image: d3 Sample]

Comment: What is your specific question? And please note StackOverflow is about coding questions. We do not advise on model building or recommendations. Other StackExchange sites do like [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and [Data Science Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) but even this question is too broad.

Comment: Please also include a sample of *d3*. Also, you appear to be overwriting *d3* by `lm` object.

Comment: Hi @Parfait thanks for the correction. my question is, how do i select the right variable for my model? I have just included the sample on my question.

Comment: Once again, that is a modeling question and not an R coding question. You show how to select all variables in model so you do not have a coding question to ask. Consider aforementioned sites for *right* variable(s) but cite your research and attempts.

Comment: Suggested (cross-site) dupe: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/326501/7515